# MongoDB Int32 Time How to format "YYYY-MM-DD hh: mm: ss" Or Other when querying

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image]

format date_time to time like "YYYY-MM-DD hh: mm: ss"

Comment: Usually you format the date in the returned object

Comment: it's not mongodb, that converts 1487736044 to int32 it's your client -what is it?..

Comment: mongobooster it is

Comment: that it is seconds, not milliseconds